# Enum values from non-integer literals?

Tags: c, enums, initialization

Is it possible in C to declare enum values from anything other than integer literals?

Answer (score 5):

No. enums are constants with type int.

Just a small addition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages

Answer (score 0):

Any expression that is composed of integer literals in the broad sense (343, 'a', L'ß') other `enum`, and `sizeof` expressions.

I am not so sure but maybe also `offsetof` expressions.